# Открыть статью в соседнем блоке div по клику на заголовок на javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть два блока. В одной развернуты пять заголовков, в другой открытая статья с картинкой. Нужно реализовать так, чтобы по клику на заголовок её id отправлялся на сервер через ajax, по этому id sql запрос выдал данные и они отразились во втором окне. То есть обновить окно читаемого контента, не перезагружая всей станицы.

На данном этапе получилось только реализовать вывод id по клику на заголовок в переменную.

```js
function tit()
{ 
alert (tit.arguments[0]) 
}
```

```html
$query = "SELECT * FROM `articles` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3,6";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{    
echo "<div id = 'title' onclick = 'tit($row[0])' class = 'block_2_2_title'>  <span id = 'tec'> $row[1]</span> </div>";
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А не проще сразу вывести весь контент, но скрыть по умолчанию через `css`. А потом через `js` просто показывать его при клике?